# Remotely run a command on a ssh-server with a script

Tags: server, ssh, scripts

I want to run a command on a ssh-server, but this command is determined by a script on my local machine. How do I do that?

An example for clarity:
I want to write a script here (*foo.sh*) that takes an argument. If I run `./foo.sh 0` it should somehow send a shutdown signal to the server machine, but if I run `./foo.sh 1` it should send a restart signal.

I know how to manually login via ssh, and I've already set ssh-keys to skip passwords, but I don't know how to automate the procedure with a script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Oli commented, you can tell SSH to send commands. You could modify your script so that if your command line arg is 1 it sends `ssh user@server "shutdown -h now"`. Keep in mind that you'll have to be superuser on the other machine to shut it down.

**EDIT**:
Instead of using root, as is suggested in the comments put `user` into the sudoers file as being able to shut down the machine without a password.

Comment: Logging remotely with root enabled is not recommended. Instead he should to setup the sudoers file to be able to execute the shutdown command without requiring a password.

Comment: Not quite true. They just have to be in the `sudoers` file as a user who can issue a shutdown without a password prompt. Not too hard to implement.

Comment: The shutdown was really just an example, you can change "root" to "user", just to make sure less knowledgeable readers don't try to remotely login as root.

Answer (score 11):

You can pass a command (or list of commands, separated by `;` [or `&&`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24685/209677)) to a SSH connection like this:

```
ssh user@server-address "./foo 1"
```

If you have a local script that outputs `0` or `1`, you can simplify things further:

```
ssh user@server-address "./foo $(/path/to/your/local/script)"
```

The code in `$(...)` executes before anything else and its output is put into the line dynamically. It's called [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [runoverssh](https://github.com/yuriescl/runoverssh):

```bsh
sudo apt install runoverssh
```

```bsh
runoverssh -n -s localscript.sh user host
```

`-n` will use SSH default authentication (your keys)
`-s` runs a local script remotely